# Need to create labels/entity types for a Custom Document Extractor using Java client libraries

Tags: java, cloud-document-ai

I have successfully created a Custom Document Extractor processor in the Google Cloud Console as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-processor). I have defined labels trained new version as well.

Also I achieved the same programmatically using the client libraries with the processor using the latest Java client library `google.cloud.documentai.v1beta3`. I am able to train models and process documents.

Is it possible to create labels / entities using the client libraries or REST calls?

Answer (score -2):

Currently, Document AI doesn't support creating labels with the REST API or client libraries.

I recommend following the [Release Notes for Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/release-notes) for updates on supported features for the product.